# getting python 2.4.5 out of my environment variables

Tags: python

major noob question:
when I run python on the windows command line, it says I have 2.4.5... however, it's not in my PATH environment variable (or anywhere in my environment variables), and, Python27 IS in PATH! Anyone know how I can get Python27 up and running in windows cmd?

Comment: Can you copy-paste the entire contents of your PATH environmental variable?

Comment: When you use the standard Windows Python installer there is an option to make this the default for the system.  Did you do this?

Comment: Why don't just just uninstall Python 2.4.5 ...

Comment: Python24 isn't even installed on my computer... let alone in my PATH variable. Can't find it anywhere! I'll look for the default option.

Answer (score 0):

Trying running WHERE PYTHON (or WHERE PYTHON.EXE) to figure out where the python executable is at.

It may be that python v2.4.5 is as part of another program.